# Getting HTTP Status 404 - /hello/?

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven

I am new to this maven - spring  project i done the coding and configurations for the project but when ever i try to run this project i am getting the 404 resource not found error

i tried this example.i follow the given directory structure in this example but it is not working it gives me the bellow error

[i tried this link](http://www.programcreek.com/2014/02/spring-mvc-helloworld-using-maven-in-eclipse/)

HTTP Status 404 - /hello/

type Status report

message /hello/

description The requested resource is not available.
Apache Tomcat/8.0.32

Can any one help me to fix this

**index.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"

pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Spring 4 MVC - HelloWorld Index Page</title>
</head>
<body>

    <center>
        <h2>Hello World</h2>
        <h3>
            <a href="hello?name=Eric">Click Here</a>
        </h3>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- <!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >
 -->

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>


  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.opine.controller" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.opine</groupId>
  <artifactId>hello</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>hello Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
        <spring.version>4.0.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Spring dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>

    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>

    <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>

    <version>2.3.1</version>


</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>


  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>hello</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

**helloworld.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Spring 4 MVC -HelloWorld</title>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <h2>Hello World</h2>
        <h2>
            ${message} ${name}
        </h2>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

**HelloWorldController.java**

```
package com.opine.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {
    String message = "Welcome to Spring MVC!";

    @RequestMapping(value="/hello")
    public ModelAndView showMessage(
            @RequestParam(value = "name", required = false, defaultValue = "World") String name) {
        System.out.println("in controller");

        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("helloworld");
        mv.addObject("message", message);
        mv.addObject("name", name);
        return mv;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the relevant parts of configuration, code and exeptions generated.

Comment: @codependent check my update

Answer (score 0):

if you are using STS IDE then open Server tab -> double click on tomcat server -> click on module tab -> click on Add Web Module and update the path with "HelloWord" and then hit the URL "http://localhost:8080/HelloWorld/hello".

Hope this will help you.

Comment: i am using eclipse marsh IDE

Comment: try to change tomcat module name, I think it will same in eclipse also.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your web.xml configuration as follows:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Edit your `context-param` as follows:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/root_context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Make a spring bean file with name `root_context.xml` inside `WEB-INF` folder with content as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->

</beans>
```